# Modal Popup and closing with sessionStorage keeping it closed

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to make a modal that will show up after a few seconds but then after you close the modal it doesn't show up unless you close the website and start a new session. I've got the modal but I'm struggling to integrate the sessionStorage

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal"\>
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <h1>I'm Dummy Body</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
      },6000)
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap, or are you making this modal on your own?

Comment: No, I'm using my own modal, from scratch, I have taking references from other places like w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting a flag in sessionStorage when the modal is closed, indicating it has been shown. When the page loads, check if the flag exists in sessionStorage. If not, display the modal after a delay. If the flag is present, do not display the modal. You can go to your dev tool and check application>session storage to see the log there. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for more information on sessionStorage.

```
      <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        // Once the modal is closed, set a flag in sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('modalShown', 'true');
        }
        
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
           modal.style.display = "none";
           // Set flag in sessionStorage when modal is closed by clicking outside
           sessionStorage.setItem('modalShown', 'true');
        }
        }
        
        // Check if the modal has been shown in this session
        var modalShown = sessionStorage.getItem('modalShown');
        
        if (!modalShown) {
        setTimeout(function(){
           modal.style.display = "block";
        }, 6000);
        }
    </script>
```